# Why is this Java method polymorphing by declared type and not runtime type?

Tags: java, polymorphism, late-binding

This code:

```
public class PMTest
{

    private static class Runner { }
    private static class Server extends Runner { }

    private static class Task
    {
        public void delegate(Runner runner)
        {
            System.out.println("Task: " + runner.getClass().getName() +
                               " / " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    private static class Action extends Task
    {
        public void delegate(Server server)
        {
            System.out.println("Action: " + server.getClass().getName() +
                               " / " + this.getClass().getName());
        }
    }


    private static void foo(Task task, Runner runner)
    {
            task.delegate(runner);
    }

    private static void bar(Action task, Runner runner)
    {
            task.delegate(runner);
    }

    private static void baz(Action task, Server runner)
    {
            task.delegate(runner);
    }


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Server server = new Server();
            Action action = new Action();

            action.delegate(server);
            foo(action, server);
            bar(action, server);
            baz(action, server);

        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

produces this output:

```
$ java PMTest
Action: PMTest$Server / PMTest$Action
Task: PMTest$Server / PMTest$Action
Task: PMTest$Server / PMTest$Action
Action: PMTest$Server / PMTest$Action
```

I can see very clearly that Task's method is being chosen over Action's method.  I don't understand why, though, since the objects always know what they are and I thought Java's late-binding method selection would be able to distinguish the difference in method signatures.  The call to `bar()` is especially confusing, as `task` is declared as an `Action` at that point.

If it makes a difference, this is Java 6:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
BEA JRockit(R) (build R27.6.5-32_o-121899-1.6.0_14-20091001-2113-linux-ia32, compiled mode)
```

I can change my code to make it work, but I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how dispatch works in java.

Dispatch is based first on static parameter types, and once a static signature has been chosen, then the runtime type of the object containing the method is used to figure out which overriding is used.

For example, in

```
void foo(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Number) { foo((Number) o); }
  else if (o instanceof String) { foo((String) o); }
}

void foo(String s) { ... }

void foo(Number n) { ... }

{ foo((Object) "foo"); }  // Calls foo(Object) which calls foo(String).
{ foo("foo"); }  // Calls foo(String) without first calling foo(Object).
```

Comment: +1: This is the right answer.  In summary, Java doesn't do *double dispatch* (although it can be emulated).

Comment: So the dispatching is based on the declared parameter type, not the runtime parameter type?  I can understand the actual rule, I suppose, but I don't understand why it would be implemented like that.  It seems like it's only somewhat late-binding then.

Comment: OK, looks like Ernest answered my follow-up on why -- thanks!

Comment: @Joe, Yes, dispatch is based on the declared type.  One reason is that it makes it easy for compilers to optimize -- that's why it was done in C++, and Java was designed to be easy for C++ developers to learn.  A reason people use to argue it should stay that way is it makes it easy for developers who know the rules to figure out what code does -- having a level of static dispatch makes code easier to review and learn.

Answer (score 5):

The choice between overloaded methods is always made at compile time, never at runtime. Runtime polymorphism involves choosing between methods that override other methods -- i.e., methods with identical signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Because once you pass `Server` into `foo` or `bar`, in the scope of that call it is not a `Server` but rather a `Runner`.

Therefore, when you run `delegate` it will bind to the most appropriate match, according to the method's signature.  `delegate(Runner)` doesn't require the dangerous downcast of the scoped parameter into a `Server`.

Note that this scoping is not done at runtime, it will hold up to static analysis of the source code too.   It's just that you remember server was a `Server` that's confusing you.  If you analyse the code without that extra out-of-scope knowledge, then you'll see that `delegate(Runner)` really is you only valid choice.